# How can i change TimeZone when using timestamps in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose, timezone

How can i change the timezone in the timestamp on mongoose?
here i have my jobSchema:

model.js:

```
const jobSchema = new Schema({
  owner: {
   type: Schema.ObjectId,
   ref: 'User',
   required: true
 },
 title: {
  type: String
 },
 description: {
  type: String
 },
 tag: {
  type: String
 },
 ....
 }, {
  timestamps: true,
  toJSON: {
   virtuals: true,
   transform: (obj, ret) => { delete ret._id }
  },
  toObject: { virtuals: true }
 })
```

the result of the time is:

```
"createdAt": "2019-01-21T04:35:20.076Z"
```

but my actuall time is 11.35 am.

I want to change the timestamp TimeZone to GMT/UTC +7.
is it possible to do this? if it possible, how can i do this? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB stores date in UTC format always. However, you can convert it to your timezone yourself or [mongoose-timezone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-timezone) to convert the dates in local timezone.